# Python, open a photo WIndows Live Photo Gallery and at the end close it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open an image with WIndows Live Photo Gallery.
The image has path:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image.jpg
```

I want to open it at the beginning of the loop and then close it a the end of the loop.

I've successfully managed to open it with:

```
img =  os.startfile("image.jpg")
```

However I can't seem to find any way to close the image at the end of the loop.

Also if any of you know any better way to call and then close an image (it doesn't need to be with Windows Live Photo Viewer).

Answer (score 0):

you better install Python Pillow module

```
from PIL import Image 

im = Image.open(r"C:\Users\System-Pc\Desktop\bla.jpg")  
im.show()
```

when done use `im.close()`

Comment: The opening part works great, however with im.close() it doesn't do anything